# xcorr in MATLAB for periodic function

Tags: autocorrelation, estimation, cross-correlation

I have a periodic signal and I want to find it's autocorrelation function.
I can calculate it exactly:

$$R_{uu}(h) = \frac 1M \sum_{k=0}^{M-1} u(k)\cdot u(k-h)$$

But will `xcorr()` use this function for periodic signals?

BTW, I've created my own function for periodic signals:

```
function [R h] = intcor(u,y) 
%Calculates the correlation between two vectors u, y   
M=length(u); 
h=0:1:M-1;  
R=zeros(M,1); 
for i=1:M    
   for k=1:M         
     if k-h(i) <= 0             
     R(i)=R(i)+u(k)*y(k-h(i)+M); %since periodic, add M -> gets same result        
   else 
     R(i)=R(i)+u(k)*y(k-h(i));         
   end  
end     
R(i)=R(i)/M; 
end 
end
```

Comment: What do the Matlab docs say about that function?

Comment: @MBaz Here you go: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html

Comment: Does not explain the periodic case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xcorr` function assumes a linear cross-correlation, i.e. it assumes that the signals are zero outside the intervals. If you want to have an efficient implementation of the periodic cross-correlation, you can refer to the properties of the Fourier transform with

$$
\mathcal{F}(u \star y)=\mathcal{F}(u) \cdot \mathcal{F}(y)^*, 
$$

while exploiting the fact, that the DFT considers signals to be periodic anyway. Here's the corresponding code for that:

```
N = 20;

u = randn(N,1);
y = randn(N,1);

R = intcor(u, y);

R2 = real(ifft(fft(u) .* conj(fft(y))))/(N);  % Calculate the periodic CC

hold off;
plot([u y R])
hold on;
plot(R2, 'ko');

legend({'u', 'y', 'intcor', 'fft-based'});
```

[image]

To answer your questions in the comments:

1. *It is still not clear to me, if I can use xcorr to calculate the autocorrelation of a periodic signal correctly?* -
   No, you cannot use the `xcorr` function, as it assumes a linear cross-correlation. What you want is a calculation, where you assume the signal is periodic, and you just input one period of the signal.
2. *What is the difference between linear cross-correlation and periodic cross-corellation?* - Consider the general equation for cross-correlation:
   $$
   R_uy(h)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}u(k)^*y(k-h)
   $$

Normally, the summation is done over all times (i.e from $-\infty$ to $\infty$). However, the signals you pass to the xcorr-function are time-limited (i.e. they consist only of $N$ non-zero samples). Now, in the linear case, the cross-correlation assumes that the input-sequences vanish for $k<0$ or $k>N-1$. In the circular-correlation (i.e. assuming periodic signals), the signals are not assumed to be zero for the index above, but instead we assume $u(k+iN)=u(k), \forall i\in\mathbb{Z}$. I.e., the sequences are assumed to be periodic with period N.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I have still some questions to ask:

Comment: 1. It is still not clear to me, if I can use xcorr to calculate the autocorrelation of a periodic signal correctly ?

Comment: 2. What is the difference between linear cross-correlation and periodic cross-corellation ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit of your answer ! It is no clear to me ! :) :)

Comment: I wanted to type: now *

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation of `xcorr` for periodic x and y

```
function out = xcorr_per(x, y)

    len = length(x);

    % make sure y is a column vector
    y_col = reshape(y, len, 1);

    index = repmat(1:len, 1, len+1);
    index = circshift(index, 1);
    index = reshape(index, len+1, len);
    index = index(2:end, :);

    out = x(index) * y_col;
```